# Youngs modulus to yield stress

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Is anybody able to shed some light onto why youngs modulus of metallic materials has little dependance on alloy composition and processing whilst the yield strength can vary greatly?

Comment: Young's Modulus is a measure of the stiffness of a material, independent of the dimensions of the material. The yield strength depends upon other factors, such as the strength of the alloy or the shape, that simply do not affect the Young's Modulus.

Comment: I found the following which provides a more complete answer than mine. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395105/why-doesnt-the-youngs-modulus-change-when-an-alloy-is-strengthened

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is Young's Modulus applies when the stresses applied to the material are relatively small resulting in small strains. At these levels the elastic properties of the material is primarily dependent on the basic composition of the material. Yield strength, on the other hand, occurs at much larger stresses where processes such as work hardening can have a significant effect on yield strength.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the modulus of the material is a function of the strength of the interatomic forces present in the metallic crystallites. Those forces are electrostatic and do not depend much on the composition of the alloy.

The yield point occurs when dislocation movement within the crystallites becomes irreversible, or nearly so. This depends on things like dislocation pinning, pileup, and entanglement at grain boundaries and solute atom sites in the lattice. It is therefore a strong function of processing history and alloy composition.